# como obtener el valor de un TEXT para ocuparlo en una funcion atra vez del metodo get() en Python 3 con tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, get, text

Estoy programado un GUI en python 3 con tkinter, El error aparece al utilizar la etiqueta TEXT en la variable self.descripcionCaja, el resto de las variables utilizan la etiqueta ENTRY

```
self.descripcionCaja = Text(
        self.ventanaVer,
        font=("times new roman", 17, "italic"),
        height=3,
        width=60,
        yscrollcommand=self.scrollbar.set,
    )

self.btnNuevoGuardar = Button(
        self.ventanaVer,
        image=self.imgBtnRegistrar,
        text=" Registrar  ",
        compound="left",
        font=("times new roman", 17, "bold"),
        relief="groove",
        borderwidth=5,
        command=lambda: self.addRegister(
            self.nombreCaja.get(),
            self.apellidoCaja.get(),
            self.telefonoCaja.get(),
            self.sexoCaja.get(),
            self.calleCaja.get(),
            self.coloniaCaja.get(),
            self.descripcionCaja1.get(),
        ),
    )
```

#Error marcado
TypeError: get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'index1'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para añadir a la anterior respuesta, y para ser un poco más detallados, sería la siguiente línea:

```
self.descripcionCaja.get("1.0", "end-1c")
```

El `1.0` es para indicar que quieres sacar desde la primera línea, del carácter cero, y `"end-1c"` indica que vas a obtener hasta el final (*end*) y restarle un char (*-1c*), se le resta uno porque sino te va a añadir una newline al final (alternativamente puedes usar `.strip()`).